# Django slow to delete rows based on Foreign Key when rows are not created through ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm

I'm encountering a situation where Django is slow to delete rows from a table when they are related to another table via a Foreign Key (FK), but were not created via the Django ORM.

I have the following Django model for `Record`:

```
class Record(models.Model):

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    record_id = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default=None)
    document = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    error = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
```

This is related to the model `Job` via the `job` column (`job_id` in MySQL after Django migration creation).

However, `Record` rows are not written via Django, but instead from Apache Spark via `jdbc.write()`.  A typical example might be 1 `Job` with 45k related `Record` rows.

The problem is, while deleting a `Job` instance via the Django ORM via `job.delete()` *does* delete the associated `Record` rows, it is quite slow, 5-7 seconds for 1 `Job` with 45k associated `Record` rows, 20-30 seconds for 160k, and so forth.

My understanding is that Django *emulates* `ON DELETE CASCADE` to accommodate different DB backends, which makes sense.  But I'm wondering: if the `Record` rows are not created via the Django ORM, does that bypass some kind of internal Django indexing that would otherwise make this cascading deletion of associated `Record` rows much faster?

The `Record` model table creation SQL looks like this:

```
core_record | CREATE TABLE `core_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_id` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document` longtext,
  `error` longtext,
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `core_record_job_id_8016b123_fk_core_job_id` (`job_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `core_record_job_id_8016b123_fk_core_job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `core_job` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=338041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As expected, there is no `ON DELETE CASCADE` for `job_id`.  But, I noticed the FK constraint has a strange `KEY` of `core_record_job_id_8016b123_fk_core_job_id`, which I thought might suggest some kind of internal Django indexing.  My understanding is that an InnoDB engine automatically indexes FK relationships, but this affordance is not leveraged when Django manages the tables via the ORM.

One approach seems like it might be to alter the `core_record` table to include `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the FK, and then instruct Django to do nothing `on_delete`, relying on MySQL to delete child rows.  But I'm wondering if there are alternatives?  I would like to avoid manually altering the table if possible, and allow Django to manage the SQL migrations.

If Django does have some kind of internal indexing for FKs, is there a way to index database/table rows in Django when the ORM did not create the rows?

Any suggestions or insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating the table outside of the Django context, but still including a model in Django for retrieving records, and updating where necessary.

The model looks thusly, with the salient bit being `managed = False`:

```
class Record(models.Model):

    '''
    DB model for individual records.
    Note: This DB model is not managed by Django.
    '''

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    record_id = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default=None)
    document = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    error = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)

    # this model is managed outside of Django
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

In some preliminary testing, deleting 150k records with FKs went from 3-4 minutes, to seconds, when relying on MySQLs built-in indexing and `ON DELETE CASCADE` settings.  Quite happy with the arrangement: ability to query conveniently in Django, but the performance of native MySQL.